# Как устроены операторы delete и delete[]?

Tags: c++, delete, void

Скажите, пожалуйста, как именно работают операторы `delete` и `delete[]`?

Например, если я сделаю так:

```
Object*const object = new Object();
void*const pointer = object;
delete pointer;
```

Сможет ли оператор `delete` корректно удалить объект через бестиповый указатель? То есть, использует ли оператор `delete` информацию, доступную во время компиляции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оператор delete вызывает деструктор, основываясь на статическом типе (тот, который он видит по объявлению указателя) и динамическом (если есть такая информация). После этого он вызывает менеджер памяти, что бы все освободить эту память. В этом случае тип указателя уже не имеет значения.

Если в delete приходит указатель "неверного типа", то будет вызван и "неверный деструктор". В некоторых случаях это может закончится плачевно. У void деструктор фактически отсутствует, значит вызывать нечего и соответственно ничего не вызовется. Если деструктор выполняет нетривиальную работу - будет не очень хорошо.

`delete[]` получив указатель, "магическим способом" получает размер массива (обычно, он хранится рядом с указателем, но это личное дело компилятора, поэтому я и написал "магическим способом"). А дальше просто в цикле вызываем `delete`. Ничего необычного. Поэтому, если попутать `delete` и `delete[]` могут быть разные непонятные баги (`delete[]` будет искать размер массива там, где его нет, а потом пойдет в разнос).

Некоторые компиляторы могут добавлять немножко больше кода для проверки себя и удалять корректно. К примеру, так может сделать visual studio  в дебажном режиме. Но я бы на это не закладывался.

Comment: *"А дальше просто в цикле вызываем `delete`"* Скорее, в цикле деструктор, а потом один раз `operator delete` на весь массив.

Comment: Да, судя по коду он так и делает. Но я думаю, что это все таки детали реализации.